# SMS gateway integration with Tigase

Tags: sms-gateway, tigase

I am using Tigase server for my application.I want to Integrate my server(Tigase) with SMS gateway. Is there any support available in Tigase.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no SMS gateway out of the box, but it is very easy to implement one. Just create a Tigase component which intercepts messages and forwards them as SMS. Some of our customers have implemented SMS, iPhone, Android, BB gateways already.